# goto() function with for loops

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm making a simple guessing game where the user has to guess one of the keys locations in a hidden map (an array) and he has 12 tries to make his guess
i almost made it but the only problem is the counter isn't changing  i want the `TryCounter` to actually count the tries when the user doesn't guess the location of a key
this is my code :

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool w;
    int x;
    int y;
    
    int array1[6][6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    cout << "game is starting ... " << endl;
    cout << "You have 12 try to find one of the hidden keys " << endl;
    loop: for (int TryCounter = 1; TryCounter <= 12; TryCounter++)
    {
        cout << " guess  " << TryCounter << "  - x and -y coordiants : " << endl;
        cin >> x;
        cin >> y;
         if (TryCounter == 12)
        {
            cout << "You have used your chances" << endl;
            if (w == false)
            {
                cout << "You lost" << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)//Drawing the hidden array
                {
                    cout << "   " << endl;
                    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                    {
                        cout << array1[i][j];
                        cout << "   ";  
                    }
                }break;
            }break;
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)//checking the input
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                if (array1[x][y] == 1)
                {
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    cout << "--- Nice Shot ! ---" << endl;
                    w = true;
                    cout << "You Won" << endl;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) //drwaing the hidden map
                    {
                        cout << "   " << endl;
                        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                        {
                            cout << array1[i][j];
                            cout << "   ";
                        }
                    }return 0;
                }
                else if (array1[x][y] == 0) //wrong guess
                {
                    w = false;
                    cout << "--- You missed ---" << endl;
                    goto loop ;
                }
            }
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: `TryCounter` is initialized after goto label. Move `int TryCounter = 1` before `loop:`.

Comment: There is no "goto function" in C++.   `goto` is a language keyword, and it is used in a goto statement.

Comment: where should i put it then ? 
i tried several locations but none of them worked @i486

Comment: @Peter 
Sorry i didn't know that I'm studying programming by my self

Comment: Don't get the downvote. Its a legitimate question, IMHO. The answer is, that you can remove the loop label and the goto. As simple as that. Then, have the for loop include the block with the checking. And remove the `if (TryCounter == 12)` check. The for loop does that already for you.

Comment: Don't use `goto` instead of loops. Add another loop if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, it looks complicated.
I've tried to understand it by doing some refactorings and I expect that you already have some bugs into it.

My suggestion would be to extract some functions out of this code.
I've already identified some duplicated code to print out the array to the std::cout.
This reduces the nesting of loops by 2 on the deepest point.

The second function would be the check function, where you check if the shot is OK or not.
Here I noticed that within the loop, you are most likely indexing the array incorrectly as your loop uses i and j (unused in the loop), while you index with x and y.

With that extracted, you end up with a single for loop, which you can continue/break with the keywords using the same name. (Here is an idea of how I understand your code should work https://compiler-explorer.com/z/TKqGMh)

My rule of thumb is that if you need to remember state about your for loops, these should be put into function.

Comment: Thank you for your replay , my code is a real mess comparing it with yours . @JVApen
Edit : I ran your code looks like the 
 `else if (array1[x][y] == 0)  // wrong guess
        {
            w = false;
            cout << "--- You missed ---" << endl;
        }` 
isn't working , It's always a win situation.

Comment: Like I said, I had to change a few things, as I assume you had a bug into it. However, I think the overall point is clear: put some stuff in a function to reduce the complexity in the other function, which makes the end result easier to maintain

Answer (score 3):

Normally people strife to program without goto. But sometimes it is indeed useful... so no judgement here.

```
int main(...) {
   // the variable and array stuff...
   for(int attemptCounter = 0; attemptCounter < 12; ++attemptCounter) {
      // the user input stuff...
      // the checking if user guessed right
      if( userGuessedCorrectly ) goto Success;
   }
   std::cout << "better luck next time, pal - you did not guess right." << std::endl;
   return 0;
Success:
   std::cout << "Congratulations you made it!" << std::endl;
   return 0;

}
```

Of course, it is only marginally harder to write this without a goto. But since you want to use it, I complied.

Comment: It's _easier_ to write this without `goto`. The use of `goto` obfuscates what is actually happening here. The use of `goto` is generally considered harmful, just as use of raw owning pointers is considered harmful. It's not a case of "not judging" as though it's a personal choice. We can criticize bad disciplines without "judging" a person. There are a few good arguments for using `goto` in C for cleanup code; there is no good argument for using `goto` in C++.

Comment: @cdhowie It depends on the metric you apply. Without the goto in this case, in which of course I agree no one would seriously use a goto, you would need to move the first term of the for loop to the outside and later add an `if(attemptCounter < 12) { ... } else {...}`, which if you apply "cyclometric complexity" metric to it is MORE complex than the goto. Just saying... not every goto is black and not everything else is white. ;)

Comment: What? You can just replace `goto Success;` with `{ std::cout << "Congratulations you made it!" << std::endl; return 0; }` in your example code. The `goto` in your code actually _obfuscates_ what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

The counter does not change because you use `goto`.  The counter changes at the end of the loop (the closing brace).  Your execution pointer never reaches the closing brace because `goto` tunnels it to the beginning of the loop earlier.